# How can I copy an array by value in Java?

Tags: java, arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Make copy of array Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5785745/make-copy-of-array-java)

I'm a beginner at Java and I need to copy the contents of one array into another variable. However, Java always passes the array by reference instead of by value.

Here's what I mean if that was confusing:

```
int test[]={1,2,3,4};
int test2[];
test2=test;
test2[2]=8;
for(int i=0;i<test2.length;i++)
    System.out.print(test[i]); // Prints 1284 instead of 1234
```

In this example, I don't want the value of `test` to change. Is this possible without using any of the more advanced features of Java such as ArrayList and Vectors?

Edit: I tried System.ArrayCopy and test.clone(), but they still don't seem to work.
Here's my actual code:

```
temp_image=image.clone();
for(int a=0;a<image.length;a++)
    for(int b=0;b<image[0].length;b++)
        image[a][b]=temp_image[image.length-1-a][b];
```

Basically I'm trying to flip the "image" upside down. Is there an error somewhere in the code?

Comment: System.arraycopy: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza you might want to start using more recent JavaDocs; [Java 1.4 is 3 versions (10 years) behind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history).

Comment: Surely there are like 2000 exact duplicates of this?

Comment: I'm pretty sure there are over 9000.

Comment: @MДΓΓБДLL well, if you check the link in your comment, it refers to `System.arraycopy` too!

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza all I meant was that you should link to [non-obsolete JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to clone your array.

```
test2=test.clone();
```

Answer (score 2):

Starting in Java 6 you can use [Arrays.copyOf](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf%28int%5B%5D,%20int%29):

```
test2 = Arrays.copyOf(test, test.length);
```

For what you're looking to do, test.clone() is fine.  But if you wanted to do a resize, copyOf allows you to do that.  I think in terms of performance it

[System.arraycopy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29) would give even more options if you needed them.

Answer (score 0):

Because test and test2 are both pointers to the same array, you are changing the value of both `test` and `test2` with your statement `test2[2]=8`

A solution would be to copy the contents of test into test 2 and change the value at the specific index of test2.

```
    for (int i=0,i<test.length,i++)
        test2[i]=test[i]
    //Now both arrays have the same values

    test2[2]=8

    for (int j=0,j<test.length,j++)
        System.out.print(test[i])
        System.out.println()
        System.out.print(test2[i])
```

Will output

```
    1 2 3 4
    1 2 8 4
```