# How to get rid of pointers?

Tags: java, pointers

To make my question understandable, I'm using the following example code. The output of this code is 5, while I wanted it to be 3. I'm guessing that B is working as a pointer for A, but I want A to be copied in B initially, and subsequent changes in A should not affect B.

```
import java.io.*;
public class fg

{

public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
{

    int[] A = new int[3];
            A[0]=1;
            A[1]=3;
            A[3]=7;

    check(A);


}

public static void check(int[] A)
{               
    int[] B = A;

    A[1] = 5;

    System.out.println(B[1]);
}
```

}

Comment: Are you looking for something like `int[] b = new int[](A);`?

Comment: `int[][] A = new int[3];` will not compile! change it to `int[] A = new int[3];`

Answer (score 5):

You need to explicitly create a copy,

```
int[] B = Arrays.copyOf(A, A.length);
```

since `int[]` is a reference type, so an assignment just copies the reference (basically, pointer).

If the array elements themselves are not primitive types, you probably will need a deep-copy, so

```
type B[] = new type[A.length];
for(int i = 0; i < A.length; ++i) {
    B[i] = makeCopyOf(A[i]);  
}
```

where `makeCopyOf()` should create a sensible copy of a `type` instance. If you don't find anything better, `type makeCopyOf(type orig) { return orig.clone(); }` could serve as a fallback.

Comment: I would question the use of clone() - see http://www.artima.com/intv/bloch13.html

Answer (score 2):

B is a *reference*, and as such is analogous to a pointer (with various differences - you can't do arithmetic and it's not a direct memory pointer).

As such, you'll have to create a [copy of the structure (the array)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5785745/make-copy-of-array-java) that you're referring to. Note that if you're copying objects, you may need a *deep copy*. You would likely have to do this in a copy constructor (see this article as to [why clone() is considered broken](http://www.artima.com/intv/bloch13.html))