# Creating a method for copying an array elements to another array in java

Tags: java, arrays, methods

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Make copy of array Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5785745/make-copy-of-array-java)

I have a main method call of `c3 = c1.replicate();`

`c1 = new Chromosome(new int[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6})`

I am trying really hard to create a replicate method in java that will copy `c1` and attach it to the `c3 = call`.

Any help would be awesome!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5785745/make-copy-of-array-java

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/80476/how-to-concatenate-two-arrays-in-java

Answer (score 2):

You can use `System.arrayCopy()` in @jsoft solution for copying array faster.

Answer (score 1):

```
public Chromosome replicate(){
  int [] newArray = new int[this.chromosomeArrayOrWhateverYouNamedIt.length];
  for(int i=0; i < this.chromosomeArrayOrWhateverYouNamedIt.length; i++){
     newArray[i]=this.chromosomeArrayOrWhateverYouNamedIt[i];
  }
  Chromosome retVal = new Chromosome(newArray);
  return retVal;
}
```

I think that should work for you.

Comment: fixed the typo, sorry bout that.