# Java Array Copy

Tags: java, arrays

I have an IntArray A.

```
int[] A={1,2,3};
```

and I copy it to B.

```
int[] B=A;
```

now I want to change element in A;

```
A[1]=B[2];
```

I would expect A now becomes {1,3,3} where B stays the same {1,2,3}.

Why is B changed to [1,3,3]?

Comment: Here's how you can do it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5785745/make-copy-of-array-java

Answer (score 3):

They both are **not individual** arrays.

You wrote

```
int[] B=A;
```

Because there are pointing to the same array.

If you change A automatically `B` changes.

If you want to make `B`  constant create a new array in the name of `B`.

```
int[] B = new int[3];
```

As you confused with pass by reference and value :[Is Java "pass-by-reference" or "pass-by-value"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference)

Comment: Thanks, then do I copy the values through a for loop?

Answer (score 3):

Because you are not copying the array, you are simple working with references.

This mean that if you create an array you are assigning a piece of memory to that variable.

```
int[] array ----------------> PieceOfMemory
```

If you "copy" the array as you did you are simply telling another variable to point to the same piece of memory

```
int[] array ----------------> PieceOfMemory <----------------- int[] secondArray
```

In this case if you change "PieceOfMemory" is clear that you are changing both of the variables.

If you want to copy the array you have to do like so:

```
int[] firstArray = {1,2,3};
int[] secondArray = new int[3];
secondArray = (int[]) clone(firstArray);
```

now what happens is this:

```
int[] firstArray ---------------------> firstPieceOfMemory
int[] secondArray --------------------> secondPieceOfMemory
```

But the values are copied.

Comment: Appreciate it. Now I do understand Java is totally pass by reference. Do I use clone to force it pass by value? Does clone works for other classes? Thanks.

Comment: I suggest you to check the javadoc and Java documentation, it's the only way to know "www": what works where. Some classes uses clone, some other don't, you can even override a default clone method or create one for your POJO (plain old java object). I also suggest you to have a look to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference

Comment: @NewbieDave Java is **NOT** pass by reference! It is always pass by value, but the value is the reference and not the referenced object.

Comment: @Gianmarco by this `secondArray = (int[]) clone(firstArray);` did you meant `secondArray = firstArray.clone();` ?

Answer (score 2):

When you do

```
int[] B=A;
```

`B` and `A` both point to *same backing array*. `B` and `A` here are just *references* pointing to same underlying array.

```
A ----->[1,2,3]
           ^
B----------|
```

To make a new copy you can use [Arrays#copyOf](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf%28int%5B%5D,%20int%29) or manually create a new array and copy fields one by one.

Answer (score 2):

You need to understand the **difference between objects and references**.

I.e. `B=A;` does **not** make a copy *of the data*, but a copy of the *reference to the data*.

Comment: Is everything in Java passed by reference? not value? so no pointer in Java?

Comment: @NewbieDave Yes.For Objects you can say pass by reference,primitives are pass by value.Again yes there is no pointers in java.Simple and clean :)

Comment: @NewbieDave No, Java is always passed by value. But the value is the reference, not the data. You always pass a reference copy to the same object.

Comment: @NewbieDave As fabian said ,That reference can be primitive value that holds the adress of that reference.

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ Actually, everything except primitives are pointers. The actual limitation is that you are not allowed to compute pointers yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Because B isn't a new array, it's just another name for the array that A refers to.

Answer (score 1):

Yes B also changed to {1,3,3} because A and B are just references actual memory where the array is stored are same for both the array so both array contains same value.