# Changing of Integer Array changes value of ArrayList

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

Things aren't happening as I believe they should, the code below is a exert of what I am doing. I create an arrayList then add an integer array to it. Then I assign a newly constructed integer array to the first element of my arraylist. I then change the value of the constructed integer array. I output both the arrayList element and the integer array and they are the same value, which shouldn't happen.

```
ArrayList<int[]> path = new ArrayList<int[]>();
int loc2[] = {0,0};

path.add(loc2);

int loc[];

loc = path.get(0);

loc[0] += 1;

System.out.println(loc[0]);
System.out.println(path.get(0)[0]);
```

The system output of the code shouldn't be the same for both lines but it is.

Am I doing something drastically wrong or do i just have a misunderstanding of what I am trying to do?

Comment: `which shouldn't happen.` why not? they are the same object

Comment: if you look at the references, loc2 == loc == path.get(0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are changed by reference.

What you are assigning to `loc` is just the "address" of `loc2`.
So whatever you are doing with `loc` is happening with `loc2` because they have the same "address".

What you need to do is to `deep copy` `loc2` to `loc` using a basic loop. For example:

```
public int[] copyArr(int[] arr) {
      int length = arr.length;
      int[] newArr = new int[length];

      for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        newArr[i] = arr[i];
      }

      return newArr;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're dealing with references to the same actual Array of Integers. You're effectively pulling 'loc2' back out and assigning it to 'loc'.

If you deal with 'loc2', 'loc' or by using path.get(0), they're the same actual Array of Integers, containing the first set of values you made when you made 'loc2'.

If you want to get a copy and work on it without altering your original Array in your ArrayList. You need to make a new Array object, copy the values into it you want and then work with that.

You could look at using System.arraycopy(). See [Make copy of array Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5785745/make-copy-of-array-java)