# Binary tree passing by reference maybe?

Tags: java, arrays, binary-tree

first time commenter here.  I'm trying to add char arrays to a Binary Tree in java.  The problem is that when I try to make the char array into a node (prior to adding the node to the tree), the node is not a char array but a reference.  Here is my making-things-a-node class:

```
public class TreeNode {

char[] data;
TreeNode left, right, parent;
public TreeNode(char[] data) {
    this.data = data;
    left = right = parent = null;
}
}
```

and here is the line I'm using to pass the char array to the node class:

```
TreeNode theNode = new TreeNode(dictionary);
```

where dictionary is a char array.  And when I print `theNode` I get something like this: `([C@58623a98)`.  I think the problem might be with the `this.data` but I'm not sure.  Can anyone help me?

Update: when I print `dictionary` I get the char array I started with.

Comment: If you want to print the content of data, use `Arrays.toString(data);`

Comment: Look into printing arrays and the inherited `Object#toString()` method.

Comment: The problem is not the printing of the array.  That works fine. The problem is making the array into a node.  Also, how would I go about making a copy in this particular case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you describe is normal behaviour. The outcome of printing an object is determined by its `.toString()` method. If no `.toString()` method is declared, the default `.toString()` method inherited from `Object` class is used, which gives the output you received.

If you want the array to look nice when printed, you can define your own `.toString()` method, or use an utility method of `Arrays.toString(yourArray)`.

Answer (score 0):

The observation is correct that each node has access to the *same* character array<sup>1</sup>;
if you *want* a copy of any object, *make* a copy of an object.

Either of the following are sufficient to [make a copy of a primitive array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5785745/make-copy-of-array-java), although `clone` has a bad reputation in general.

```
this.data = Arrays.copyOf(data, data.length);
this.data = data.clone();
```

Alternatively, you could make it the *callers* responsibility to pass in different objects.

```
// i.e. when omitting the above
new TreeNode(dictionary.clone());
```

More complex objects/object-graphs will require different handling. My recommendation is to simply try and *reduce* mutable objects which eliminates the need for making the appropriate copies.

---

<sup>1</sup> That is, objects are *not* copied/cloned/duplicated when they are passed in Java; rather, [the *value of the reference to the object* is passed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference?answertab=votes#tab-top), and hence the *same* object is referred to.

Comment: That did not work, but it seems like it should.  I still have the same output as before.  Perhaps my problem lies not where I thought it did.

Comment: @jani Oh, I see. Your printing issue is *unrelated* to the above.

Comment: @jani See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/409784/simplest-way-to-print-an-array-in-java