# Method is changing values of my array unexpectedly

Tags: java, arrays

Method calculating percentages (from array which I don't want to be changed but it is):

```
private float values[] = { AGREE, DISAGREE };

private float[] calculateData(float[] data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    float total = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        total += data[i];
    }
    // 180 is the amount of degrees of the circle - setting it up to half
    // circle 360 means full circle
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        data[i] = 180 * (data[i] / total);
    }
```

Calling the method:

```
float[] degrees = calculateData(values);
```

If I log the values of array before this method was called I get 1.0,1.0 but after method was called I get 90.0,90.0 why? If I don't change `values[]`.

I know that it is happening here in that method because when I remove it I get 1.0,1.0 (what I actually want to get)

EDIT:

Thank you for the answers so if I understand it correctly: if parameter of the method is changed also the object set to be parameter, when method was called, becomes changed.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference

Comment: Java is passing parameters by reference value, so you modify contents of `values` array when you pass its reference to the method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are modifying your array here: `data[i] = 180 * (data[i] / total);`

You get the address of the array in the parameter of your function, not a copy of it, so if you modify it in your function, it will modify the array you passed when walling your `calculateData` function.

Answer (score 1):

You are modifying the array in the second for

Answer (score 1):

Array variables are just references. If you pass `values` as `data`, `data` points to the *same* array as `values`. Consider the following example:

```
int[] a = new int[] {1, 2, 3};
int[] b = a;
b[0] = 4;

// a is now {4, 2, 3}
```

If you don't want this, you need to **make a copy**:

- [Make copy of array Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5785745/87698)

Answer (score 1):

You need a new array inside your method like `newData` in the code below, which you need to `return` from a method:

```
private float[] calculateData(float[] data) {

    float[] newData;

    float total = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        total += data[i];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        newData[i] = 180 * (data[i] / total);
    }

    return newData;
}
```