# incorrect variable change in java

Tags: java, variables

I have a problem in Eclipse. Why is the value of `oldList` different in LogCat while I don't change it between the tow Log command?

First I have an `initialize` method:

```
private void initialize() {

    list[0][0] = 2;
    list[0][1] = 4;
    list[1][0] = 3;
    list[1][1] = 7;

    oldList = list;

    going();
}
```

and in the `going` method, I printed `oldList` twice :

```
private void going() {

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
            Log.i("Log", "oldList = " + oldList[i][j]);
        }
    }
    Log.i("Log", "---------------------------");

    //    ----------------------------------------------------
    list[0][0] = 0;
    list[0][1] = 5;

    list[1][0] = 0;
    list[1][1] = 0;
    //    ----------------------------------------------------

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
            Log.i("Log", "oldList = " + oldList[i][j]);
        }
    }
}
```

but the two results is different in LogCat :

```
oldList = 2
oldList = 4
oldList = 3
oldList = 7
---------------------------
oldList = 0
oldList = 5
oldList = 0
oldList = 0
```

While i don't change it between the two logs. I just change the value of `list`, not `oldList`. Why does the output change?

Comment: [Is Java “pass-by-reference” or “pass-by-value”?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value) relevant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this :

```
private void initialize() {
   list[0][0] = 2;
   list[0][1] = 4;
   list[1][0] = 3;
   list[1][1] = 7;

   // simply
   oldList[0] = list[0].clone();
   oldList[1] = list[1].clone();

   // or in a greater 2D arrays
   for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
      System.arraycopy(list[i], 0, oldList[i], 0, list[0].length);
   }

   going();
}
```

Comment: @Reza: Hello, if the answer is ok for you, can you accept it plz?

Comment: Hello , answer is ok but what is your mean about accept ?

Comment: Thanks . it's done. but it was my first question and i recieved answer soon. but my second question has not been answered yet . why ? it is about animation of 2048 Game .

Answer (score 4):

Both `list` and `oldlist` refer to the exact same object. When you run

```
oldlist = list
```

you have two different "names" referring to the exact same object in memory. When you assign an object (in your case the array) to a variable, this object will not be copied.

Thus, as you change the `list` array in your `going` method, you are changing the object referred to by both `list` and `oldlist`.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer . so if i want to protect the value of oldList i must assign each cells of list to the similar cells in oldList , not assign like : oldList = list ;

Comment: You can copy your existing `list` array instead of just assigning it. See [Make copy of array Java](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5785745/421705) for details.

Answer (score 3):

`oldlist` and `list` are two references that point to the same array.