# Copying an Array won't work JAVA

Tags: java, arrays, copy

I'am trying to copy or duplicate an Array without success

```
   for (int i=0;i<x*y+y;i++)
                {


                    tmpInt = br.read();
                    //Wenn i%x 0 ist dann brakeY eins hochzählen, um damit die Anzahl der Zeilen zu bekommen
                    if (i%x==0 && brakeY<y-1) brakeY++;

                    if (tmpX<=x-1) tmpX++;
                    else tmpX = 0;

                    // Beim ersten Ausführen dieser Teilfunktion wird das Array aus der Textdatei ausgelesen. Beim zweiten Mal jedoch gibt es nur den aktuellen Stand der Map wieder um Veränderungen zu sehen.

                    spielFeld[tmpX][brakeY] = (char) tmpInt; 

                   System.out.print(spielFeld[tmpX][brakeY]);

                //System.out.println("----------");


                }
```

I'am trying to copy the Array, called spielFeld (german for playground), in this line  `spielFeldT = spielFeld.clone();` , (`spielFeldT = spielFeld` didn't work either) so that I can interact with it globally. The results are:

```
1xwvutsrqpo
2     ü   n
3   !öä   m
4   "     l
5 K §$%   k
789abcdefgh
```

which is exactly how it's should look like,
but if I'am tyring to print the copied array exactly the same way as I printed this one something like this appears.

```
1     ü   �
3   !öä  �n
4   "   � l
5 K §$%�  k
6     � fgh
789abcdefgh
789abcdefgh
```

Comment: Please format your code propperly. You may want to take a look at [Java's `System.arraycopy(...)` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy-java.lang.Object-int-java.lang.Object-int-int-). It is expected, that `clone()` does not work since this method is inherited from `Object` and not overwritten (and, therefore, empty).

Comment: `System.arraycopy()` did not work? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5785745/make-copy-of-array-java

Comment: I tried " System.arraycopy(spielFeld, 0, spielFeldT, 0,spielFeld.length); ". Still getting an error.

Comment: run:
1xwvutsrqpo
2     ü   n
3   !öä   m
4   "     l
5 K §$%   k
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
6     &   j
789abcdefgh
 at java.lang.System.arraycopy(Native Method)
 at project.project.readSpielFeld(project.java:87)
 at project.project.main(project.java:21)
/Users/project:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`System.arraycopy(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy-java.lang.Object-int-java.lang.Object-int-int-) method.

Here is the Syntax of the method,

```
public static void arraycopy(Object src, int srcPos, Object dest, int destPos, int length)
```

For further information, you may want to [take a look at this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5785745/make-copy-of-array-java).

Comment: The method is called `System.arraycopy(...)`, not `System.arrayCopy(...)`. Also, you may want to write your code as codeblock, not as text.

Comment: Ok I am new to stack overflow. I will do that

Comment: @Sudha would you be so great and change this Method for my purpose? I'am still getting a NullPointerException

Comment: @Hames, Can you please provide your code(full program) to check the null pointer exception?