# Java taking new array as input though i give the source twice

Tags: java, arrays

In my previous question, I came to know how can I find Index value of Max Value in Array.

Now my problem is I'm trying to make 2 different Arrays by swappingthe array[0] with Max Value and another swapping array[0] with Min Value.

Here I'm able to do it, but the problem is, first I'm swapping array[0] with Min Value. And when I'm trying to swapping array[0] with Max Value, The array that is getting called in is the array output after swapping array[0] with Min value, but not the actual array in input.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Cook {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int num[] = { 3, 1, 5, 2, 4 };
        int start = 0;
        int maxEnd = getMaxValue(num);
        int minEnd = getMinValue(num);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(num));
        getMinvalueString(start, maxEnd, minEnd, num);
        getMaxvalueString(start, maxEnd, minEnd, num);
    }

    private static void getMinvalueString(int start, int maxEnd, int minEnd, int[] num) {
        int[] num1 = num;
        int temp = num1[start];
        num1[start] = num1[minEnd];
        num1[minEnd] = temp;
        System.out.println("After replace Min: " + Arrays.toString(num1));

    }

    private static void getMaxvalueString(int start, int maxEnd, int minEnd, int[] num) {
        int[] num1 = num;
        int temp = num1[start];
        num1[start] = num1[maxEnd];
        num1[maxEnd] = temp;
        System.out.println("After replace: " + Arrays.toString(num1));

    }

    public static int getMaxValue(int[] num) {
        int maxValue = num[0];
        int getMaxIndex = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < num.length; i++) {
            if (num[i] > maxValue) {
                maxValue = num[i];
                getMaxIndex = i;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(getMaxIndex);
        return getMaxIndex;

    }

    public static int getMinValue(int[] array) {
        int minValue = array[0];
        int getMinIndex = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (array[i] < minValue) {
                minValue = array[i];
                getMinIndex = i;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(getMinIndex);
        return getMinIndex;
    }

}
```

Here Though I've made a new array `num1`, the same old array(`num`), is getting swapped. Please let me know how can I fix this.

**Current Output**

```
[3, 1, 5, 2, 4]
After replace Min: [1, 3, 5, 2, 4]
After replace: [5, 3, 1, 2, 4]
```

**Expected Output**

```
[3, 1, 5, 2, 4]
After replace Min: [1, 3, 5, 2, 4]
After replace: [5, 1, 3, 2, 4]
```

Thanks

Comment: What are you expecting as output?

Comment: I think you want to copy the array. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5785745/make-copy-of-array-java

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`num1` refers to the same array an `num` in both `getMinvalueString` and `getMaxvalueString` methods, so making changes in `num1` affects the same array referred by `num`, which is the same array you declared an initialized in your `main` method.

If you wish to keep the original array unchanged, pass a copy of the array to each method :

```
    getMinvalueString(start, maxEnd, minEnd, Arrays.copyOf(num,num.length));
    getMaxvalueString(start, maxEnd, minEnd, Arrays.copyOf(num,num.length));
```

Comment: The methods affecting the array are `getMinvalueString` and `getMaxvalueString` though.