# Passing an Array and sort

Tags: java, arrays, bubble-sort

Good day guys, I am trying to sort here using an array, Check my codes

```
 public int[] Sort(int[] arr) {
   int[] value = arr;
   int min, temp, out;


   for (out = 0; out < value.length - 1; out++) {
       for (min = out + 1; min < value.length; min++) {
          if(value[out] > value[min]){
            temp = value[min];
            value[min] = value[out];
            value[out] = temp;
           }
       }
      }
     return value;
 }
```

The problem here is I pass the array 'arr' value to the array 'value' and sort the 'value' array then the output is what i expect, he sorted the number, but the problem is, when i tried to return the 'arr' array it also return a sorted value even though i didn't tried to sort it .. is it a bug or just my ugly coding ?

Comment: `int[] value = arr;` is referring, not copying the contents.

Comment: You can use int[] value = arr.clone();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your variables `arr` and `value` both point to the *same* array.

Apparently you thought your sorting manipulations were applied to a second array. But, no, you were changing the original array.

Learn about reference variables. The two variables are not an array themselves, they are a pointer *to* an array that lives elsewhere in memory. So there are *three* “things” in play here. One reference variable, another reference variable, and an array. All three are distinct from one another.

When these reference variables go out of scope or get assigned to another object, so no more reference variables point to the array object, then the array object becomes a candidate for [garbage collection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/usingobject.html).

Seems that you want to copy the array to another array. Stack Overflow has [many Questions and Answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Java+copy+array) on the topic of [copying an array in Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) for you to study. Like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5785745).

Answer (score 1):

When you make the assignment `int[] value = arr`, you give `value` the same reference as `arr`.  This means that assigning, for example, `value[1]` will affect the original array.  If you want to return a *new* sorted array without affecting the original one, then you can try making a copy of it:

```
public int[] Sort(int[] arr) {
    int[] value = new int[arr.length];
    System.arraycopy(arr, 0, value, 0, arr.length);

    // ...
    return value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach, You'd clone the array and sort

```
int[] value = arr.clone();
```

any operation on the cloned array wont affect the original array.

**Ex**

```
    int[] arr = { 1, 4, 3 };
    int[] a = arr.clone();
    a[2] = 5;
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
```

**output**

```
[1, 4, 3]
[1, 4, 5]
```