# How do I create an array with both its size and contents being parameters?

Tags: java, arrays, parameters, nodes

I'm trying to create a node which contains a int array thats size is determined by an int value taken as a parameter, this is what I have so far. It works fairly well but when I go to fill it it will take arrays of any size which is not what I want. thank you.

```
public Node(int size, int [] contents, Node<T> t) {
    size = size;
    intArray = new int[size];
    intArray = contents;
    tail = t;
  }
```

Comment: You need to remove `intArray = contents;`Loop through `contents` array and set value in your `intArray`

Comment: Don't assign contents to intArray. Use System.arraycopy to copy the contents. Also verify that array sizes match before copying.

Comment: You can also use System.arraycopy() instead of looping over the array. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5785745/make-copy-of-array-java

Answer (score 0):

So here...

```
intArray = new int[size];
intArray = contents;
```

You are first initializing the array variable to an array of the size you want, but then you are re-assigning the array variable to the array passed in as an argument.  You will need to copy or truncate the passed in array somehow.

Take a look at `[System.arraycopy][1]`.  You could do something like...

```
intArray = new int[size];
System.arraycopy(contents, 0, intArray, 0, size);
```