# Bubble sort function does not sort the given array

Tags: java, arrays, bubble-sort

So basically, I have set up bubblesort algorithm and weirdly enough it does not return the sorted array just the unsorted array.

The given array;

```
int[] array = { 20, 5, 1, 6, 23, 52, 15, 12 };
```

Bubble sort algorithm;

```
public static int[] sort_array(int[] array) {

    int [] sorted = array;
    int temp = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < sorted.length - 1; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; i < sorted.length - i - 1; i++) {
            if (sorted[j] > sorted[j + 1]) {
                temp = sorted[j];
                sorted[j] = sorted[j + 1];
                sorted[j + 1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    return sorted;
}
```

Also made an array return method;

```
public static void return_list(int[] array) {

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(array[i]);
    }
}
```

After the methods are used it just returns me the unsorted array.

```
int[] array = { 20, 5, 1, 6, 23, 52, 15, 12 };

sort_array(array);

return_list(array);
```

Output = 20, 5, 1, 6, 23, 52, 15, 12;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Duplicating an array (assuming you want to keep the original one)

First, you're not copying `array` into `sorted` here. You're copying a reference of array to sorted, so any change to the contents of `sorted` will also be seen in `array`

```
int [] sorted = array;
```

Do this to instantiate a new array `sorted` and copy contents from `array` into it:
[Make copy of array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5785745/make-copy-of-array)

There are several ways (Arrays.copyOf, clone, etc.) to do an array copy. For example:

```
int[] sorted = Arrays.copyOf(array, array.length);
```

### Sorting bug

Also, it looks like there may be a bug in your for loops. You're not iterating through `j` in this line

```
for (int j = 0; i < sorted.length - i - 1; i++)
```

So, the reason it looks like you're getting an unsorted array is that the array isn't being sorted correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You are checking for the value of i every time as well as increasing its value on every iteration of

```
for (int j = 0; i < sorted.length - i - 1; i++)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug:
Replace i by j here ->for(int j=0;i(here)