# Java variable is changing without assignment

Tags: java

I don't understand why the variable `initialCoordinates` is changing. When I run the program, `initialCoordinates` changes values after each run of the loop.

```
int[] initialCoordinates = { 26, 0 };
int[] positions = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
int[][] coordinates = { { 0, 0 }, { 0, 0 }, { 0, 0 }, { 0, 0 } };
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    System.out.println("Initial: " + initialCoordinates[1]);
    coordinates[i] = initialCoordinates;
    coordinates[i][1] += positions[i];
}
```

Comment: Have you tried stepping through with a debugger and watching the initialCoordinates vairable?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You need to read up on references in Java. An array variable has reference type.

Comment: Arrays are references in Java, which emits these sort of bugs in what was conjected to be a safe language. Upvote for sympathy!

Comment: and there are no 2 dimensional matrix, just array containing arrays...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In your example you're setting `coordinates[i]` to `initialCoordinates`.

Then in the next line you're executing `coordinates[i][1] = ...`, that's when you're accesing `initialCoordinates` indirectly through `coordinates[i]` and changing the the value of `initialCoordinates[1]`.

Comment: To add, if you do not want intialCoordinates to change. You need to create a copy of the array initialCoordinates in every iteration and assign that to the coordinates[i]. See [how to create copy of an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5785745/make-copy-of-array)

Comment: Does this issue also exist in C#, or any other languages. Also, is there a specific reason why this exists?

Answer (score 2):

As Mark said, you are accessing `initialCoordinates` with the `coordinates` variable because you assigned it by reference. This means that after `coordinates [i]=initialCoordinates;`, `coordinates[i]` will then reference the same memory address that `initalCoordinates` does so that when one changes the other changes also.

What you probably wanted to do is copy the values which would have the effect of assigning it by value. You can do that using [System.arraycopy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy(java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int)) (See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5785754/3291390)). By assigning by value, you allocate a separate chunk of memory to hold the values for `coordinates[i]` which will be copied from `initialCoordinates` rather than having both variables pointing to the same thing in memory.

```
int [] initialCoordinates = {26,0};
int [] positions={1,2,3,4};
int [][] coordinates = {{0,0},{0,0},{0,0},{0,0}};
for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
    System.out.println("Initial: "+initialCoordinates[1]);
    System.arraycopy(initialCoordinates, 0, coordinates[i], 0, initialCoordinates.length);
    coordinates [i][1]+=positions[i];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I will attempt to show you, what is approximately going on in java memory.

- first you created instances in the `stack`, which points to objects in the `heap`

[image]

- then you changed the pointer of `coordinates[0]`, and both variables - `initialCoordinates` and `coordinates[i]`  point to the same object in the `heap`

[image]

- so, when you changed `coordinates[0]`, you also changed the object in the heap. The `initialCoordinates` also refers to object in the heap, so `intialCoordinates` were also "changed"..

[image]

Comment: I like this explanation however there are a lot of typos in your text & images. And in your last image only `coordinates[0]` points to something but there's not a single arrow to `coordinates` in the heap.