# is unsafe to copy a three-dimensional array using Arraylist?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, unsafe

I wonder if can I copy a 3-dimensional array, using ArrayList<>() as a middle step.

Please, consider the following code:

```
        /*variable declaration*/
        int[][][] array;
        int[][][] array2;
        ArrayList<int[][][]> list;
        ArrayList<int[][][]> list2;

        /*initialization*/
        array = new int[10][12][14];
        list = new ArrayList<>();

        list.add(array);

        //Construct 'list2', using all the elements contained in 'list'
        list2 = new ArrayList(list);

        array2 = list2.get(0);
```

I wonder if array2 is a complete copy (*deep copy*) of array, or is array2 a reference to array (*points to same object in memory*).

Also, is this an unsafe operation?

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, it would be a reference to the existing object. Try comparing via `==`

Comment: Just try, change value on one array, and print the other one, you'll see. This answer is no, an array is an object, you don"t make a copy here

Comment: @tucuxi, If I ask is because I have tried and I have not de capacity to verify it...

Comment: you should have included the code that you used to try it; it helps in several ways: proves that you have tried, and allows feedback on how to test it better. I will be happy to reverse my downvote if you edit your question to include the test that did not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both `val` and `val2` point to the same object in memory even after you've cloned the first list into the second.

You can prove this with:

```
System.out.println(val == val2);
```

prints "true"

That said, note that when you pass a collection to the `ArrayList` copy constructor all it does is simply construct a list containing the elements of the specified collection so I am not sure why you expected it to perform some type of "deep copying"

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList<int[][][]> vec2=new ArrayList(vec);
```

Here you are creating a new instance of `ArrayList`, but both `vec` and `vec2` are referencing the same three-dimensional array.

You can look to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5785745/make-copy-of-array). Here the Java 8 documentation for [System.arraycopy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy-java.lang.Object-int-java.lang.Object-int-int-)