# I want to transfer the element of an array to another array

Tags: java, arrays

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args){

        int array1[] = {5,8,11,1,6};
        int array2[] = new int[5];

        for(int transfer=4; transfer<array1.length; transfer--){
            array2=array1;
            /*this is line 9*/System.out.print(array2[transfer] + " ");
        }

    }
}
```

OUTPUT:

6 1 11 8 5 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
    at Test.main(Test.java:9)

Comment: By far, the best way to understand where your code is going wrong is to use the debugger built into your IDE to step through your code statement by statement, watching the values of your variables. Using a debugger isn't just for advanced coders. It's fundamentally the next thing you should learn how to do after "Hello, world."

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Make copy of an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5785745/make-copy-of-an-array)

Answer (score 2):

Your program runs as long as transfer is smaller than the length of the first array, and it starts at, which is already smaller, and gets reduced by 1 each turn, so it will naturally try to access  array2[-1].

Additionally, you have to use

```
array2[transfer] = array1[transfer]
```

instead of your current transferring, as this copies the whole array at once.

Comment: *"...as this copies the whole array at once."* It doesn't **copy** the array, it just makes the variable point to the array, so both variables are pointing to the same array.

Answer (score 0):

`transfer` starts at `4` and all your code ever does is decrement it (make it smaller, `4` to `3`, `3` to `2`, etc.). Your loop continues as long as `transfer<array1.length` is true. Since `array1.length` is `5`, and `4` (and `3`, and `2`, ...) is less than `5`, the loop will continue **forever** or, in this case, until you try to access the entry at index `-1` because `transfer` has been decremented five times.

Comment: I think my question is not clear, I apologize for that. What I mean is that, I want to transfer the elements of Array1 to Array2 and print it in reverse. 


This is what I've come up with:

int array1[] = {5,8,11,1,6};
  int array2[] = new int[5];
  
  for(int transfer=4; transfer<array1.length; transfer--){
   array2=array1;
   System.out.print(array1[transfer]+ " ");
   
    if(transfer<=0){
     return;
    }
   }

Output:
6 1 11 8 5 

Is there an another way without using if and Arrays.copyOf?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Arrays to to copy values in a new array like this :

```
int array1[] = {5,8,11,1,6};
int array2[] = Arrays.copyOf(array1, array1.length);
for (int i = 0; i< array1.length; i++) System.out.print(array2[i] + " ");
```