# Why convert an array to a list to an array again

Tags: java, performance, optimization, spring-batch, code-cleanup

I have been working with SpringBatch and looking the sourcecode of the class

```
org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.BeanWrapperFieldExtractor<T>
```

And I have found this:

```java
public void setNames(String[] names) {
    Assert.notNull(names, "Names must be non-null");
    this.names = Arrays.asList(names).toArray(new String[names.length]);
}
```

- What is the purpose of converting an array into a list into an array again?
- Why not use something like this:

```java
public void setNames(String[] names) {
    Assert.notNull(names, "Names must be non-null");
    this.names = names; // Simpler and without conversions
}
```

- Or this to create a new instance isolated:

```java
public void setNames(String[] names) {
    Assert.notNull(names, "Names must be non-null");
    this.names = names.clone(); //Simpler and create a new instance
}
```

All answers all welcome.

Comment: I cannot think of a specific reason not to use clone, but there are good reasons to copy the names.

Comment: This is just a not-very-efficient way to create a copy of array. `.clone()` will do the same, but likely in more performant way. Also, supplying a non-empty array in `toArray()` call is now considered a [bad practice](https://shipilev.net/blog/2016/arrays-wisdom-ancients/). You may submit an issue at https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/issues

Comment: So the code wants to have an independent copy, that cannot be changed from the outside. Maybe the programmer did not remember `clone` or `Arrays.copyOf`.

Comment: Look up "defensive copying", it's the name of this technique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is usually done to create a copy of the supplied array although it's easier to do with [`System.arraycopy()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5785754/1602555).

The copied array is needed to make the receiving object immutable. Consider the following example without the copy being done:

```
String[] names = { "John", "Pat", "Willy" };
obj.setNames(names);
names[0] = "Nathan";
// at which point obj.names also has Nathan
```

Comment: Doesn't `clone` also do this?

Comment: Yes ... but `<shrug>`.