# Remove in Array list of array lists

Tags: java, arraylist

```
public Point{
int x, y;

public Point(int x, int y){
    int x = x;
    int y = y;
    // setters
    // getters
    // toString
}
}
```

```
ArrayList<Point> points = new ArrayList<>();

// add points by using points.add() then use this loop 
ArrayList<ArrayList<Point>> A = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            A.add(points);

        }
```

I have an arraylist of arraylists that each of them have the same points
For example when you print this is the output

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Point>> A = [[(0,10), (20,3), (2,5), (2,8)], [(0,10), (20,3), (2,5), (2,8)], [(0,10), (20,3), (2,5), (2,8)]]
```

I want to remove all the points that their x value is not equal to the index of the array list before printing

```
A.get(0) = [(0,10)]
A.get(1) = []
A.get(2) = [(2,5),(2,8)]
```

so the output should be

```
[[(0,10)], [], [(2,5), (2,8)]]
```

I tried to use remove method and for loop and other ways but they didn't work.

```
for(int i = 0; i < list.size();i++){
            if(list.get(i).x != 0){
                list.remove(i--);
            }
        }
```

Is there anyone who can help?

Comment: can you please add your code here?

Comment: Your problem is here:
A.add(points);
You are adding THE SAME array 3 times. It's not 3 copies of the array, it's the same array. That's why when you follow my answer you are getting empty arrays.

Comment: This is how you can do a copy: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5785745/make-copy-of-an-array

Comment: "*I have an arraylist of arraylists that each of them have the same points For example when you print this is the output `ArrayList<ArrayList<Point>> A = [[(0,10), (20,3), (2,5), (2,8)], [(0,10), (20,3), (2,5), (2,8)], [(0,10), (20,3), (2,5), (2,8)]]`*" are you sure that this is what you *have* or do you just *assume* that you have it?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for something like this:

```
int index = 0;
for (ArrayList<Point> list : A) {
     list.removeIf(point -> point.x != index);
     index++;
}
```

*`index`* variable could be removed as well but I didn't want to oversimplify the code, to preserve clarity.

Comment: Maybe you could update your answer to show how you are trying to do that

Comment: Won't even compile.  Nasty thing about effective final values in lambdas.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class teste {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList<Point> points = new ArrayList<>();

        points.add(new Point(0, 10));
        points.add(new Point(9, 10));
        points.add(new Point(20, 3));


        System.out.println(points);
        //solution 1
        List<Point> list = points.stream().filter(o -> !o.equals(9, 10)).collect(Collectors.toList());
        System.out.println(list);
        
        //solution 2
        List<Point> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
        points.stream().forEach(o -> {
            if (o.equals(9, 10)) {
                list2.add(null);
            } else {
                list2.add(o);
            }
        });

        System.out.println(list2);
    }



    public static class Point {
        int x, y;

        public Point(int x, int y) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }

        public String toString() {
            return "(" + x + ", " + y + ")";
        }

        public boolean equals(int x, int y) {
            return this.x == x && this.y == y;
        }

    }

}


[(0, 10), (9, 10), (20, 3)]
[(0, 10), (20, 3)]
[(0, 10), null, (20, 3)]
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way. To account for change in indexed position when removing items, start at the end and move backward.

- iterate over the list of lists.
- for each inner list, iterate backwards and remove the unwanted points

```
for (int i = 0; i < lists.size(); i++) {
    List<Point> points = lists.get(i);
     for (int k = points.size()-1; k >= 0; k--) {
         if (points.get(k).x != i) {
             points.remove(k);
         }
     }
}
```

Given the current data, here is the output.

```
[[(0, 10)], [], [(2, 5), (2, 8)]]
```

Here is a stream version if you're interested. This doesn't explicitly remove anything.  It just filters out the unwanted values.

- stream the indices of the outer list
- using map, stream the inner list.
- filter out the unwanted points
- and repackage into a list of lists

```
List<List<Point>> result = IntStream.range(0,lists.size())
              .mapToObj(i->lists.get(i).stream()
              .filter(point->point.x == i)
              .toList()).toList();
```

Comment: Didn't understand at first.  Please check out my updated answer.