# How do I split a list with fixed size number into another list?

Tags: java, spring-boot

So I have a loop in regex,

```
List<String> data = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> inputData = // String array

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
inputData.forEach(i -> {
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(i);
    while(matcher.find()) {
        data.add(matcher.group().trim());
    }
});
```

Now data will have an array of strings like this,

```
data = ['text', 'text2', 'text3', 'text4', 'text5', 'text6']
```

I want to divide this array of strings into a fixed size of 3.

```
data = [['text', 'text2', 'text3'], ['text4', 'text5', 'text6']]
```

Comment: You need to make two arrays and copy manually.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Make copy of an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5785745/make-copy-of-an-array)

Comment: You are asking about arrays, but your example is showing *List*. Those are different types, with different API, syntax, and properties.

Comment: yeah my bad, it should be list.

Comment: Feel free to correct it. Use [edit] option to clarify your question (specifically its title).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to split this list into sublist with fixed size - you can use Guava, or smth else

You can find related docs here - https://guava.dev/releases/31.0-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Lists.html#partition(java.util.List,int)

Example:

```
    List<Integer> intList = Lists.newArrayList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8);
    List<List<Integer>> subSets = Lists.partition(intList, 3);
```