# Searching for the fastest way to copy arrays in Java, and why `Arrays::copyOf` and `System::arraycopy` feel so slow

Tags: java, arrays, performance

## **Introduction**

The primary question I am asking here is, "Why does `System::arraycopy` and feel so slow?". `Array::copyOf` is also mentioned here since as will be noted in the background - my version of Java uses System::arraycopy in its implementation.

## **Background**

I was developing a fast method for creating deepcopies of an array in Java. I did some tests to confirm that `Array:copyOf(array,length)` and `Object::clone()` were equivalent in speed (https://stackoverflow.com/a/15962949/21941522). I after a bit of research I realized my (Eclipse Adoptium jdk-21.0.1.12-hotspot's) of implementation of `Array::copy` was basically just making a fancy call to `System::arraycopy` thus I started using that instead. After about 1.5 hours of coding and testing I ended up with this (NOTE: Lines 17-19 it will become very important later):

```
class ArrayDeepCopy {
    public static Object deepCopy(Object array) {
        if (array == null) {
            return null;
        }
        if (!array.getClass().isArray()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Argument is not an array");
        }
        return deepCopyV5(array);
    }

    static Object deepCopyV5(Object array){
        final Class<?> componentClazz = array.getClass().componentType();
        final int length = Array.getLength(array);

        if (!componentClazz.isArray()){
            Object ret = Array.newInstance(componentClazz,length); //Line 17
            System.arraycopy(array, 0, ret, 0, length); //Line 18
            return ret; //Line 19
        }
        else{
            Object[] retObjectArray = (Object[]) Array.newInstance(componentClazz, length);
            Object[] oObjectArray = (Object[]) array;
            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                retObjectArray[i] = deepCopy3(oObjectArray[i]);
            }
            return retObjectArray;
        }
    }
}
```

Out of curiousity I wrote the following helper method - as an alternative meeans of shallow copying arrays:

```java
    /**
     * @apiNote this function has no type or legnth safety. Use with discretion and care.
     */
    private static Object dumbCopy(Object array, Class<?> componentType, int length){
        switch (componentType.getName()) {
            case "boolean":
                boolean[] retBooleanArray = new boolean[length];
                boolean[] oBooleanArray = (boolean[]) array;
                for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
                    retBooleanArray[i] = oBooleanArray[i];
                return retBooleanArray;
            case "byte":
                byte[] retByteArray = new byte[length];
                byte[] oByteArray = (byte[]) array;
                for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
                    retByteArray[i] = oByteArray[i];
                return retByteArray;
            case "short":
                short[] retShortArray = new short[length];
                short[] oShortArray = (short[]) array;
                for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
                    retShortArray[i] = oShortArray[i];
                return retShortArray;
            case "int":
                int[] retIntegerArray = new int[length];
                int[] oIntegerArray = (int[]) array;
                for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
                    retIntegerArray[i] = oIntegerArray[i];
                return retIntegerArray;
            case "long":
                long[] retLongArray = new long[length];
                long[] oLongArray = (long[]) array;
                for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
                    retLongArray[i] = oLongArray[i];
                return retLongArray;
            default:
                Object[] retObjectArray = (Object[]) Array.newInstance(componentType, length);
                Object[] oObjectArray = (Object[]) array;
                for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
                    retObjectArray[i] = oObjectArray[i];
                return retObjectArray;
        }
    }
```

I then replaced Lines 17-19 with `return dumbCopy(array,componentType, length);`.

## **Strange Findings**

This change, resulted performance (speed of my algorithm) imporving by a factor of 1.8 times. Thus, I decided to do some tests some tests using a type safe vesions of dumbCopy against `Array::copyOf`; even with all the added checks I still got slightly superior performance.

However, this comparison was somewhat biased and unfair since `Array::copyOf` and what I was using were different. Hence, the most logically step was meant implementing my own version of `System::arraycopy`.

## **Stranger Findings**

Hence, why I carefully created a method that closely mimicked `System::arraycopy`'s behaviours and error handling. This yielded the following:

```java
class MyArrayCopy{
    /**
     * Blind implementation of {@link System::copyarray}
     *
     * @param      src      the source array.
     * @param      srcPos   starting position in the source array.
     * @param      dest     the destination array.
     * @param      destPos  starting position in the destination data.
     * @param      length   the number of array elements to be copied.
     * @throws     IndexOutOfBoundsException  if copying would cause
     *             access of data outside array bounds.
     * @throws     ArrayStoreException  if an element in the {@code src}
     *             array could not be stored into the {@code dest} array
     *             because of a type mismatch.
     * @throws     NullPointerException if either {@code src} or
     *             {@code dest} is {@code null}.
     */
    public static void arraycopy(Object src, int srcPos, Object dest,int destPos, int length){
        if (src==null || dest==null)
           throw new NullPointerException();
        if (!src.getClass().isArray())
            throw new ArrayStoreException("arraycopy: destination type "+src.getClass().getName()+" is not an array");
        if (!dest.getClass().isArray())
            throw new ArrayStoreException("arraycopy: source type "+dest.getClass().getName()+" is not an array");

        if (length<0)
            throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException("arraycopy: length "+length+" is negative");

        final int srcLength = Array.getLength(src);
        final int destLength = Array.getLength(dest);

        String tmp;
        if (srcPos<0){
            tmp = dest.getClass().componentType().getName();
            tmp = tmp.substring(0,tmp.length()-1)+srcLength+"]";
            throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException("arraycopy: last source index "+srcPos+" out of bounds for "+tmp);
        }
        if ((srcPos+length)>srcLength){
            tmp = dest.getClass().componentType().getName();
            tmp = tmp.substring(0,tmp.length()-1)+srcLength+"]";
            throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException("arraycopy: last source index "+(srcPos+length)+" out of bounds for "+tmp);
        }
        if (destPos<0){
            tmp = dest.getClass().componentType().getName();
            tmp = tmp.substring(0,tmp.length()-1)+destLength+"]";
            throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException("arraycopy: last destination index "+destPos+" out of bounds for "+tmp);
        }
        if ((destPos+length)>destLength){
            tmp = dest.getClass().componentType().getName();
            tmp = tmp.substring(0,tmp.length()-1)+destLength+"]";
            throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException("arraycopy: last destination index "+(destPos+length)+" out of bounds for "+tmp);
        }

        Class<?> componentType = src.getClass().componentType();

        int i = -1;
        try {
            switch (componentType.getName()) {
                case "boolean":
                    boolean[] retBooleanArray = (boolean[]) dest;
                    boolean[] oBooleanArray = (boolean[]) src;
                    while (++i < length)
                        retBooleanArray[destPos + i] = oBooleanArray[srcPos + i];
                    return;
                case "byte":
                    byte[] retByteArray = (byte[]) dest;
                    byte[] oByteArray = (byte[]) src;
                    while (++i < length)
                        retByteArray[destPos + i] = oByteArray[srcPos + i];
                    return;
                case "short":
                    short[] retShortArray = (short[]) dest;
                    short[] oShortArray = (short[]) src;
                    while (++i < length)
                        retShortArray[destPos + i] = oShortArray[srcPos + i];
                    return;
                case "int":
                    int[] retIntegerArray = (int[]) dest;
                    int[] oIntegerArray = (int[]) src;
                    while (++i < length)
                        retIntegerArray[destPos + i] = oIntegerArray[srcPos + i];
                    return;
                case "long":
                    long[] retLongArray = (long[]) dest;
                    long[] oLongArray = (long[]) src;
                    while (++i < length)
                        retLongArray[destPos + i] = oLongArray[srcPos + i];
                    return;
                default:
                    Object[] retObjectArray = (Object[]) dest;
                    Object[] oObjectArray = (Object[]) src;
                    while (++i < length)
                        retObjectArray[destPos + i] = oObjectArray[srcPos + i];
            }
        }
        catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ArrayStoreException("arraycopy: type mismatch: can not copy " +componentType+"[] into "+ dest.getClass().getComponentType().getName()+"[]");
        }
    }
}
```

After repeated testing on my machine I found that as the size of array copied became large the difference between in performance between `System::arraycopy` and `MyArrayCopy::arraycopy` became smaller (see `Benchmarking`). For particularly large arrays the two methods became comparable, which I found to be surprising as `System::arraycopy` is an `@IntrinsicCandidate` with no body - indicating it is programmed in hand-written Assembly.

This leads me to my core question: Why is `System::arraycopy` so slow? From my understanding, a complex method programmed in low level machine code should (in theory) be significantly faster than my high level code. I have neither the technically knowledge nor the proficiency in Assembly to understand why `System::arraycopy` and `MyArrayCopy::arraycopy` perform comparably.

## Update

Based on findings of bechmarks I believe the underylying algorithm that uses `System::arraycopy` is potentially similar to that used by `MyArrayCopy::arraycopy`, hence why for large array sizes - the performances are similar.

## Benchmarking

Here is the (JMH) micro-benchmark I used:

```java
/**
 * Based on <a href="https://www.baeldung.com/java-system-arraycopy-arrays-copyof-performance">...</a>.
 */
@BenchmarkMode(Mode.AverageTime)
@State(Scope.Thread)
@OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS)
@Warmup(iterations = 6,time = 1)
@Fork(1)
@Measurement(iterations = 32,time = 1)
public class Main{
    //small->large
    @Param({"16", "131072", "1048576", "33554432", "134217728", "268435456"})
    public int SIZE;

    private int[] src;
    private final static Random RNG = new Random();

    @Setup
    public void setup() {
        src = new int[SIZE];
        for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
            src[i] = RNG.nextInt();
        }
    }

    @Benchmark
    public int[] systemArrayCopyBenchmark() {
        int[] target = new int[SIZE];
        System.arraycopy(src, 0, target, 0, SIZE);
        return target;
    }

    @Benchmark
    public int[] arraysCopyOfBenchmark() {
        return Arrays.copyOf(src, SIZE);
    }

    @Benchmark
    public int[] myArrayCopyBenchmark(){
        int[] target = new int[SIZE];
        MyArrayCopy.arraycopy(src, 0, target, 0, SIZE);
        return target;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        org.openjdk.jmh.Main.main(args);
    }
}
```

I used JMH version: 1.37, and VM version: JDK 21.0.1, OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, 21.0.1+12-LTS

These are the results:

```
Benchmark                         (SIZE)  Mode  Cnt          Score          Error  Units
Main.arraysCopyOfBenchmark            16  avgt   32         15,665 ±        1,438  ns/op
Main.arraysCopyOfBenchmark        131072  avgt   32      62291,965 ±     2209,779  ns/op
Main.arraysCopyOfBenchmark       1048576  avgt   32     516024,890 ±    16084,284  ns/op
Main.arraysCopyOfBenchmark      33554432  avgt   32   36857139,340 ±  1195232,132  ns/op
Main.arraysCopyOfBenchmark     134217728  avgt   32  135363432,422 ±  1813848,937  ns/op
Main.arraysCopyOfBenchmark     268435456  avgt   32  283043854,479 ± 19383044,887  ns/op
Main.myArrayCopyBenchmark             16  avgt   32         18,909 ±        1,462  ns/op
Main.myArrayCopyBenchmark         131072  avgt   32      91904,843 ±     1108,220  ns/op
Main.myArrayCopyBenchmark        1048576  avgt   32     930400,328 ±    28759,328  ns/op
Main.myArrayCopyBenchmark       33554432  avgt   32   34127154,968 ±   276304,955  ns/op
Main.myArrayCopyBenchmark      134217728  avgt   32  141763929,996 ±  5236420,825  ns/op
Main.myArrayCopyBenchmark      268435456  avgt   32  274237539,844 ±  4147450,919  ns/op
Main.systemArrayCopyBenchmark         16  avgt   32         13,210 ±        1,060  ns/op
Main.systemArrayCopyBenchmark     131072  avgt   32      61760,112 ±     1799,776  ns/op
Main.systemArrayCopyBenchmark    1048576  avgt   32     557320,496 ±    93964,190  ns/op
Main.systemArrayCopyBenchmark   33554432  avgt   32   31385267,021 ±   442441,135  ns/op
Main.systemArrayCopyBenchmark  134217728  avgt   32  120457178,472 ±  1990808,784  ns/op
Main.systemArrayCopyBenchmark  268435456  avgt   32  240560833,750 ±  2045734,195  ns/op
```

## Edits:

- corrected "digression" to "discretion", added Benchmarking section, edited language used to be more concise and less opinionated/emotional, removed sub-question on asking for suggestions on how to improve my deepcopy algorithm, updated benchmarking.

Comment: Java has a JIT. Multiple optimizations are performed on the byte code. Anyway, have fun [down the rabbit hole](https://youtu.be/HBKVdJph_oQ).

Comment: Old but good reading https://shipilev.net/blog/2016/arrays-wisdom-ancients/

Comment: You've clearly invested a lot of work here, but you haven't provided _any_ concrete statistics to demonstrate your claims.  The JIT will optimize things, but it has to warm up and that can take a lot of iterations.  [How do I write a correct micro-benchmark in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/504103/18157)  Also, unless you're going to be doing array copy on millions to billions of objects, this is probably premature optimization.  Hard numbers would help justify this.  Also, _"Use with disgression"_... I think you meant "discretion".

Comment: BTW an `Object[]` still can contain other (sub)arrays, but `componentType()` will still return  `Object.class`

Comment: Stackoverlow is not a discussion forum. It is a Q&A site with very specific guidelines. Among them don't make multiple questions into one, don't ask or offer opinion or emotional arguments. Please limit to facts and code. See the other comments too.

Comment: I would definitely suspect your benchmarking technique.

Comment: In the current Java source, System.arraycopy is a native method.  I don’t feel like digging up the native code for it, but I do know that, at least in the x86 family, it can be done with a few assembly instructions.  Do you think your custom implementation will be faster than that?