# data member is declared private but I'm able to modify it directly

Tags: java

here I'm modifying the marks[0] = 70 after creating the object Stu1, but I'm able to modify it directly even though the data member is private and not using setter method, why?

```java
public class Student {
    
    private String name;
    private int[] marks;
    
    public Student(String name, int[] marks ) {
        this.name = name;
        this.marks=marks;           
    }
 
    public int[] getMarks() {
        return marks;
    }
}
```

```java
public class Main {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
   
       int[] marks= {90,85,80,95,100} ;             
   
       Student Stu1 = new Student("Alex",marks);        
       System.out.println(Stu1.getMarks()[0]);//90              
   
       marks[0] =70;        
       System.out.println(Stu1.getMarks()[0]);//70  
   }
}
```

Comment: You have created only one array and you are changing exactly that array. Arrays are objects.

Answer (score 7):

### One array, two references

You have a single array but two *references*. Both references point to the same array.

- The `marks` variable in your `Main` class does *not* hold an array; it holds a reference (pointer) to an array.
- The `marks` private member field in your `Student` class does *not* hold an array; it holds a reference (pointer) to an array.

In your constructor method, you pass a reference to an array, not the array, not the array’s contents. So both the original `marks` variable and the `marks` member field both refer to the same array. Therefore either reference can be used to change the contents of the one-and-only array.

#### Defensive copy

To isolate the member field from such external changes to the array’s contents, your constructor should make a defensive copy. See [*Make copy of an array*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5785745/642706).

```
public Student( final String name, final int[] marks ) {
    this.name = name ;
    this.marks = marks.clone() ;           
}
```

In this revised code, we have *two* separate arrays rather than one.

Answer (score 1):

In java arrays are reference types. Not value types. You can not create an array in stack memory in java. The solution is simple.

```
     Student std = new Student("Alex", new int[]{1, 2, 3});
```

Answer (score -2):

Since the marks array has been created under static block therefore marks array has become static.

Now the Student class object

```
 Student  stu= new Student("Ajit", marks);
```

Here we are passing parameter using call by reference method. No separate copy of marks array will be created for Student class.

Therefore if you change the array item from Student class , it will be reflected on main method also. Alternatively if you change array item from main method it will be reflected on Student class also.